# easy_install clobbers my easy-install.pth and drops the python-commands in the beginning and end of the file

Tags: python-2.7, installation, setuptools, easy-install

I am facing a strange problem with my `sys.path`; Since I am going to describe the problem clearly this post is going to be a little long one.

my `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth` looks like this:

```
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg
./jmespath-0.9.3-py2.7.egg
./chardet-3.0.4-py2.7.egg
./certifi-2018.01.18-py2.7.egg
./urllib3-1.22-py2.7.egg
./requests-2.18.4-py2.7.egg
./docutils-0.14-py2.7.egg
./python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.7.egg
./enum34-1.1.6-py2.7.egg
./six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
./ipaddress-1.0.18-py2.7.egg
./asn1crypto-0.22.0-py2.7.egg
./idna-2.6-py2.7.egg
./pyOpenSSL-17.2.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-2.0.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cffi-1.10.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

With this things work fine for me; specifically, correct version of `pyOpenSSL` gets included in my `sys.path`:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# python -c "import OpenSSL; print OpenSSL.__version__"
17.2.0
```

when I remove the first and last lines the python commands my `pyOpenSSL` version changes; which means when my `easy-install.pth` looks like this:

```
./setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg
./jmespath-0.9.3-py2.7.egg
./chardet-3.0.4-py2.7.egg
./certifi-2018.01.18-py2.7.egg
./urllib3-1.22-py2.7.egg
./requests-2.18.4-py2.7.egg
./docutils-0.14-py2.7.egg
./python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.7.egg
./enum34-1.1.6-py2.7.egg
./six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
./ipaddress-1.0.18-py2.7.egg
./asn1crypto-0.22.0-py2.7.egg
./idna-2.6-py2.7.egg
./pyOpenSSL-17.2.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-2.0.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cffi-1.10.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
```

then the `pyOpenSSL` version is an older version:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# python -c "import OpenSSL; print OpenSSL.__version__"
0.13.1
```

I think this is because an older version of pyOpenSSL is present over here `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyOpenSSL-0.13.1-py2.7.egg-info`

so my first question: ***What are those commands doing in `easy-install.pth` and how is `easy-install.pth` processed to change my `sys.path`?***

Next is when I try to install new python packages using `easy_install` (from their source code) it clobbers my `easy-install.pth` -- in the sense that all packages would still be there but without the first and last lines (those python commands).

To be more concrete: I am trying to install `idna-2.5` and it does successfully installs but messes up `easy-install.pth`

```
[root@sandbox idna-2.5]# easy_install .
Processing .
Writing /opt/proj/sbs-installs/COSpkgs/idna-2.5/setup.cfg
Running setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /opt/proj/sbs-installs/COSpkgs/idna-2.5/egg-dist-tmp-sLNbiE
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tools'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Removing /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna-2.5-py2.7.egg
Moving idna-2.5-py2.7.egg to /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Removing idna 2.6 from easy-install.pth file
Adding idna 2.5 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna-2.5-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for idna==2.5
Finished processing dependencies for idna==2.5
```

Notice that it uninstalled `idnz 2.6`. After this my `easy-install.pth` looks like this:

```
./setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg
./jmespath-0.9.3-py2.7.egg
./chardet-3.0.4-py2.7.egg
./certifi-2018.01.18-py2.7.egg
./urllib3-1.22-py2.7.egg
./requests-2.18.4-py2.7.egg
./docutils-0.14-py2.7.egg
./python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.7.egg
./enum34-1.1.6-py2.7.egg
./six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
./ipaddress-1.0.18-py2.7.egg
./asn1crypto-0.22.0-py2.7.egg
./pyOpenSSL-17.2.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-2.0.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cffi-1.10.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
./idna-2.5-py2.7.egg
```

and now when I check the pyOpenSSL version it the old one (as mentioned above):

```
[root@sandbox ~]# python -c "import OpenSSL; print OpenSSL.__version__"
0.13.1
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: So the next question is: Why does `easy_install` remove those python commands from `easy-install.pth`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took some digging to find the answer. I am posting the answer here for the sake of completeness and searchability :).

The python command at the beginning of `easy-install.pth` is called [prelude](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v40.6.2/setuptools/command/easy_install.py) and the one at the last line is called [postlude](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v40.6.2/setuptools/command/easy_install.py) (in [setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/tree/v40.6.2) code).

As is expected `easy_install` re-writes the `PathDistributions`, i.e. `easy-install.pth`, if you installation leads to removal of an old package and installation of your new package.

Now if you want to include the `prelude` and `postlude` the code expects `SETUPTOOLS_SYS_PATH_TECHNIQUE` environment property to be set to `rewrite` (default value is `raw`). To put it more concretely, following commands fixed the problem:

```
[root@sandbox idna-2.5]# export SETUPTOOLS_SYS_PATH_TECHNIQUE=rewrite
[root@sandbox idna-2.5]# easy_install .
Processing .
Writing /opt/proj/sbs-installs/COSpkgs/idna-2.5/setup.cfg
Running setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /opt/proj/sbs-installs/COSpkgs/idna-2.5/egg-dist-tmp-gE1V2U
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tools'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Removing /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna-2.5-py2.7.egg
Moving idna-2.5-py2.7.egg to /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Removing idna 2.6 from easy-install.pth file
Adding idna 2.5 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna-2.5-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for idna==2.5
Finished processing dependencies for idna==2.5
[root@sandbox idna-2.5]#
```